# Office JS API versions updating

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

I have a few questions regarding the **Office JS API** library.

1. Currently, version 1.11 is the newest one. Where could we find the information when the next releases are planned (for example, "1.12 is planned to be released in November" or smth like it)?
2. If Microsoft updates an API version to 1.12, does it mean that our API version will be updated automatically, without any changes on our side? Or we can "freeze" version 1.11 and do not update it until the time we want?
   The last question raised, because we are scared of the breaking changes that may be deployed by Microsoft, and we want to be sure that API verion will not be updated without warning.
   Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Office JS API for Excel is now released version 1.12, you could find more information here: [What's new in Excel JavaScript API 1.12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/excel-api-1-12-requirement-set?view=excel-js-1.11), also you could find more about requirement set there.

When update to 1.12, the new Excel after the version showed in the wiki could be automatically supported using 1.12, the existing 1.11 version APIs won't be removed or behavior changed in new versions, new version just add new APIs.